# nn.Linear should be mismatch, but it works successfully

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm confused about the in-feature of nn.linear. For out-feature of the model VGG-19's last nn.MaxPool2d, the tensor size is (512, 7, 7). The model below uses pooling function and resizes the tensor to (512, 49), then uses nn.linear(512, 7) directly. Why can't it work successfully without mismatch problem?

[source](https://github.com/WuJie1010/Facial-Expression-Recognition.Pytorch/blob/master/models/vgg.py)

```py
'''VGG11/13/16/19 in Pytorch.'''
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable


cfg = {
    'VGG11': [64, 'M', 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 'M'],
    'VGG13': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 'M'],
    'VGG16': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M'],
    'VGG19': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M'],
}


class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vgg_name):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        self.features = self._make_layers(cfg[vgg_name])
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(512, 7)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.features(x)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = F.dropout(out, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        out = self.classifier(out)
        return out

    def _make_layers(self, cfg):
        layers = []
        in_channels = 3
        for x in cfg:
            if x == 'M':
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
            else:
                layers += [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, x, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                           nn.BatchNorm2d(x),
                           nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
                in_channels = x
        layers += [nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=1, stride=1)]
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

Comment: question flagged for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ZF007 I do not agree that this question is better suited for Cross Validated. Because this is an actual question about programming. Please check out what's on on-topic there, they explicitly refer to SO for programming questions.

Comment: @blue-phoenox... I hope mkisantals' answer will give you insight your comment was a bit off. The question is about interpretation of the method related to the dataset. Not the "why is `F.dropout(out, p=0.5, training=self.training)` not working" type of question; required to be an SO main site question ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot see what makes you think this question is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the assumption that this code works? I tested it, and got the following shapes, and the expected size mismatch error.

```
def forward(self, x):
    out = self.features(x) # torch.Size([1, 512, 7, 7])
    out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)  # torch.Size([1, 25088])
    out = F.dropout(out, p=0.5, training=self.training)  # torch.Size([1, 25088])
    out = self.classifier(out)  # RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 25088], m2: [512 x 7]
    return out
```

One mistake that you made with inferring the sizes, is that you omitted the batch dimension. That is why you may falsely conclude that the shape change with `out.view(out.size(0), -1)` is [512, 7, 7] -> [512, 49] instead the correct [b, 512, 7, 7] -> [b, 25088] where b is the batch size.

As expected when classifier is changed to

```
self.classifier = nn.Linear(25088, 7)
```

then the forward function works, no size mismatch error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very helpful. I figure out that the input image size is also important for the size mismatch problem. The input image size is 48* 48* 3 for my case, then the out-feature of the model VGG-19's last nn.MaxPool2d should be 512* 1* 1.